# How do i unlock the third option in the apply for production?

Tags: google-play-console

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGIOi.png)

On March 5th, I uploaded my game to the play store after finishing internal testing & closed testing. Now that I am in the production process, I have added 20 testers. How do I unlock the third option? .The testers have to login for 14 days consistently every day, or just login once, and do they have to verify their identity?

Comment: This question does not appear to be [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/12567365).